# FileWatcher Error, Internal buffer overflow

Tags: azure, deployment

After a deploy, my Sitecore Azure instance is heavily slowed down and I get the following error on and on,

```
2017-06-29T08:22:15  PID[42864] Error       54964 08:22:15 ERROR Error in FileWatcher. Internal buffer overflow.
Exception: System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException
Message: Too many changes at once in directory:D:\home\site\wwwroot\.
```

I tried the dark magic of "change sitecore license file location" [described here](https://mikael.com/2016/01/sitecore-file-watcher-internal-buffer-overflow-exception/) but it had no effect

What can I do to remove this error / speed up the instance so that contributors can do their work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We currently have the same issue and have been advised to set the following config (in **Sitecore.config**) to a higher value:

```
<setting name="Media.FileSystemWatcher.BufferSize" value="16384" />
```

We are currently trial & erroring this value right now, but others have reported a positive outcome.

Comment: I had same issue and this settings change works for me.+1

Comment: when you say "We are currently trial & erroring this value right now", what is the drawback of having a too high value ?

Comment: Memory usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916595/is-it-really-that-expensive-to-increase-filesystemwatcher-internalbuffersize

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue and acknowledged by Sitecore. Whilst it is being further investigated, Sitecore recommend in their [Knowledge Base article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/983839) one of the following solutions:

- Disable Dynamic Cache by creating an App Setting for the impacted App Service:

  - **App Setting Name:** WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE
  - **App Setting Value:** 0
    [image: WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE]
- Updating Sitecore Configuration and disable  `\wwwroot\App_config\Include\Sitecore.Diagnostics.config` file as mentioned in the [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6400/135) from @Tom Dudfield

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Sitecore config `Sitecore.Diagnostics.config` seems to have resolved the issue for us, this stops data being written to the diagnostics folder.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider disabling/deleting the FileWatchers completely. In general, we do this because we won't make any changes to the filesystem outside of a deploy (we don't change views, configs etc. and we only upload medias through Sitecore, not by using the file system). Hereby we save the additional work-load and threads caused by the FileWatchers, but keep the watchers locally so you can make changes without recycling the application...